# star rating int

Tags: jquery, initialization, rating, rating-system

I got the stars to be initialized from a selected value.

The problem is when I click the stars, the whole stars initialization is messed up.

I will appreciate if anyone could help me with a better and more consistent way of initializing the stars.

The code for the stars can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/wSMEc/6/

Thanks

Comment: `value` is not a string, it is an integer. `value = value.toString().substr(a,b)`.

Comment: still not working. can you think of any other way to initialize the stars.

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't see where the initialization was taking place as the focus change only operates when a user clicks on a star.  I think it also would be better to pull the value out of the focus change function and set it in the ready function.

The following works although it can be further cleaned up in a couple places.  Like you don't maybe want to set slots to 5 in case you wanted to change your rating system from 1 to 5 stars to 1 to 10 stars and other hardcoding avoidance.

```
function init(value, slots) {
   vstring = value.toString();
   vlength = vstring.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < vlength; i++)
   {
      character = vstring.charAt(i);
      charNumber = slots - Number(character);
      rgroup = 'rating' + i;               
      $('input:radio[name='+rgroup+']')[charNumber].checked = true;  
   }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var value   = 2123;
   var slots = 5;
   $('.rating').focus();
   init(value, slots);

   $('.rating').bind('focus change', function(event) {
   changed = event.target.id;
   var id_number = changed.split("star")[1] - 1;
   var row = Math.floor(id_number / slots);
   var col = id_number % slots;
   var stringValue = value.toString();

   stringValue = stringValue.substr(0, row) + col + stringValue.substr(row + 1);
   value = Number(stringValue);

   var rgroup = $(this).find("input:last").attr('name');
    alert(rgroup);

   $('input:radio[name='+rgroup+']')[value].checked = true;
});
```